# move up and down in directory structure to access file

Tags: c#, .net

A seemingly simple problem turns out quite difficult. I would like to move up two directories and then down to access a file. This:

```
var currentDir = DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

gives me the current directory. I can then do:

```
currentDir.Parent
```

this moves me up but I now get the relative path. How can I avoid it to use:

```
Path.Combine
```

or something similar to then go down?

Comment: Why not use Path.Combine? Do you look for something like currentDir.child?

Comment: Mmmh I guess that's the only way to go down ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `currentDir` is a `DirectoryInfo` `currentDir.Parent` gives you the `DirectoryInfo` of the parent directory including the full-path and all other informations of `DirectoryInfo`.

You have to use it's `FullName` property:

```
string fullPath = parent.FullName;
```

If you want to find the file:

```
FileInfo[] files = currentDir.Parent.Parent.GetFiles("FileName.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Comment: I thought so. Unfortunately, I used a slash to much when I tried to combine things using Path.Combine. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Something like below will work.

```
DirectoryInfo currentDir = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(currentDir.Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\test\\myFile.txt");
```

Comment: I think this is rather messy, so I used Path.Combine. I guess it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Yes it is. Path.Combine is better :)